# How is this Microsoft website communicating with my operating system to see the status of the troubleshooting program I downloaded?

Tags: windows-10, firefox, operating-systems, html5

On this Microsoft [website](https://solutions.diagnostics.support.microsoft.com/run/6b089dc3-50d6-4add-9959-337fca72c533#) there is a diagnostic tool that I downloaded to fix the Windows store. Once I ran the tool the website provided the status of the app.

I don’t understand how the website is able to break the barrier and communicate with my operating system to get output from this app. Is there a new feature of HTML5 that I don’t know about?

Edit: I am using Firefox 46.

[image]

Comment: I don't know that particular app, but the app itself could deliver the data to a server in the cloud which could then make it available to the web site.

Comment: You have connected your local profile to your Microsoft Account.  You should provide a screenshot, because the url, isn't very helpful.

Comment: We need screenshots for a proper answer.  Please update your question.

Comment: I have added an image. Also I am using Firefox and have not logged in to that website.

Comment: @JakeGould - I know because the author is attempting to repair the Windows Store, which if used, likely means he linked his profile to a MS account

Comment: @GabrielFair - That is the application, it is displaying a progress of its work, that is all.  That is the FixIt application not your browser, there is no interaction with anything,except its own progress.

Answer (score 2):

The premise of your question is this:

> How is this Microsoft website communicating with my operating system
>   to see the status of the troubleshooting program I downloaded?

Which is assuming the Microsoft owned/operated/managed webpage is communicating with your local Windows setup. This doesn’t seem to be the case.

I am on Mac OS X and since I can’t see the full contents of the webpage or what it does, when [I visit that site](https://solutions.diagnostics.support.microsoft.com/run/6b089dc3-50d6-4add-9959-337fca72c533#) I see the following:

[image]

Note there is a button named “Run” on that page. If I click that link it downloads an `.exe` file to my system which I—being on Mac OS X—cannot run, but I assume that `.exe` is a binary that would run on your system to repair the issue *and* share info about what was repaired with the remote website.

As for how that data is then presented on the website, it could be a simple POST string or something along those lines that are sent to that webpage and the webpage then displays the info in a nice, clean, human readable format.

But at no point do I believe that Microsoft webpage is communicating with your Windows install. Your visiting that page downloaded an `.exe` that would do the “heavy lifting” of repairing your local system and then just send a status report back to that webpage when all was done.